# Keep Getting an "Array to string conversion" Error when trying to run concatenation method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm working on a problem where I need to convert an array of values into a string so that it can be displayed for an excel document. But I keep on getting an "Array to string conversion" error when I try to run the export. The code is

```
$counties = "";
if(isset($forms->form_info['county'])){
  for($i = 0; $i < count($forms->form_info['county']); $i++){
    if(is_int($i / 10) && $i != 0){
      $counties .= $forms->form_info['county'][$i] . ",\n";
    } elseif($i == (count($forms->form_info['county']) - 1)) {
      // Keep getting the error on the line below
      $counties .= $forms->form_info['county'][$i] . " ";
    } else {
      $counties .= $forms->form_info['county'][$i] . ", ";
    }
  }
}
```

I've done a dd of a gettype on counties as well as the form element I'm trying to use, and both appeared as strings, so I'm lost on where the supposed array that's being converted is. I've tried making $form->form_info['county'][$i] into its own variable and concatenating it to the counties variable but received the same issue.

The result of dd($forms->form_info['county'][$i]); is

```
"Bernalillo County"
```

The result of dd($forms->form_info['county']); is

```
array:1 [▼
   0 => "Bernalillo County"
]
```

The result of a dd(var_dump($forms->form_info['county'][$i])); is

```
string(17) "Bernalillo County"
null
```

And here is the direct screenshot of the issue

[image: Php error screen]

Comment: what you getting when you do `print_r($forms->form_info['county'][$i]);`?

Comment: I get "Bernalillo County"

Comment: Try @Oras answer.

Comment: Don't use `print_r()` for debugging, use `var_dump()`, `var_dump($forms->form_info['county']);` `var_dump($forms->form_info['county'][$i]);`

Comment: simply, post your code with line numbers alongside with the error stack trace for better debugging ...

Comment: Hey, please wrap that instruction in a try - catch block and then dump the $forms->form_info['county'] within it.

Comment: Also, I simplified your `for, if, else` blocks with a simple 

`$counties = implode(
  ", \n",
  array_map(
    function($group) { return implode(', ', $group); },
    array_chunk($forms->form_info['county'], 10)
  )
);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the data is not what you expect, but this code is very verbose for what you're trying to do: separate the array values with commas, putting a line break after every tenth element. We can do that easily with use of [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/array_chunk).

```
<?php
$data = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
$output = "";

foreach(array_chunk($data, 10) as $v) {
    $output .= implode(", ", $v) . ",\n";
}
// get rid of that final comma space
echo substr($output, 0, -2);
```

Output:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j,
k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
u, v, w, x, y, z
```

Adapting to your code:

```
$counties = "";
if(isset($forms->form_info['county'])){
    foreach(array_chunk($forms->form_info['county'], 10) as $v) {
        $counties .= implode(", ", $v) . ",\n";
    }
    $counties = substr($counties, 0, -2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255289/miken32) for his solution to get me most of the way there. The fix came from a simple if statement that is checked before the foreach. So the solution ended up being:

```
  $counties = "";
  if(isset($forms->form_info['county'])){
    if(count($forms->form_info['county']) < 2){
      $counties = $forms->form_info['county'][0];
    } else {
      foreach(array_chunk($forms->form_info['county'], 10) as $v) {
        $counties .= implode(", ", $v) . ",\n";
      }
      $counties = substr($counties, 0, -2);
    }
  }
```

But the real reason that the function was failing, was that the data I had been using was cast as an array(explode) rather than just an explode, so it was actually a multidimensional array.

Comment: My code gives the same result with a single value in the array, i.e. the single value.

Comment: Also, while you are free to answer your own question, if you use another answer, it's generally common courtesy to upvote and mark it accepted, rather than post another, nearly identical, answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers/

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this well, you're expecting an array from `$forms->form_info['county']` ?

if that's the case please use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Your code would be:

```
if(isset($forms->form_info['county']) && is_array($forms->form_info['county'])){
   $countries = implode(",", $forms->form_info['county']);
}
```

Comment: That's why he is using the loop for that, so he can parse the array. Implode will just return a string with comma delimiter.

Comment: Which is creating anyway... `$counties .= ..."` `implode()` is faster.

Comment: It is faster for a simple case, but the logic that OP tries to apply in his code won't work.

Comment: Whereas it may indeed be faster and easier to implement it does not satisfy the formatting the OP uses in the question!